# Nonintrusive serializer to human readable format

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I need to dump an object of a 3rd-party class in a readable format, so I cannot provide DataContract attributes for this class or to add default constructor required by XmlSerializer. Implementing custom serialization is not desirable too, just because the main purpose is debugging and it can be applied to many different classes. I'm looking for a serializer which inspects given object by reflection (only public part?) and dumps it to something readable, even XML would work ;)

Comment: [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)?

Comment: I'd suggest the json.net usually works better in any non-trivial scenario, but indeed - JSON is probably the thing to look at here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON format is pretty human readable: [`JavascriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is built into the framework and would allow you to serialize any instance to JSON format. Limitations apply of course: if your object graph contains circular references you will not be able to JSON serialize it.

Comment: Circular references are however handled by the JSON.Net serializer. Also, much more.

Comment: Seems like it's part of "System.Web.Extensions" assembly. I don't see it in the list when trying to add a reference in C# ConsoleApplication project.

Comment: Make sure you are targeting the Full Framework in the properties of the project and not only the Client Profile.